# Add new textfield when pressing button

Tags: flutter

I'm making an app where users are supposed to input instructions into textfields. As I don't know how many steps there are I want them to be able to add a new textfield at the press of a button. [Picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5acUe.png)

I've created a custom class for the text form fields:

```
class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onSaved;
  final int maxLines;
  final int maxLength;
  final bool isAmount;
  final Function onTap;

  MyTextFormField({
    this.labelText,
    this.validator,
    this.onSaved,
    this.maxLines = 1,
    this.maxLength = 30,
    this.isAmount = false,
    this.onTap,
});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      maxLines: maxLines,
      maxLength: maxLength,
      validator: validator,
      onSaved: onSaved,
      onTap: onTap,
      keyboardType: isAmount ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        ),
        labelText: labelText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a part of the code I've got right now:

```
          //Steps
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: MyTextFormField(
              labelText: "Step 1",
            ),
          ),
          Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Add step"),
                onPressed: () {
                  //Add new text input field
                },
              ),
          ),
```

The entire code can be found here:

https://codeshare.io/GkLqlO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a List

```
class ListViewAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListViewAddState createState() => _ListViewAddState();
}

class _ListViewAddState extends State<ListViewAdd> {

  int steps = 1;

  List<Widget> buildsteps() {
    List<Widget> l = [];

    for (int i = 1; i <= steps; i++)
      l.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: MyTextFormField(
          labelText: "Step ${i}",
        ),
      ));

    l.add(
      Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Add step"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              steps++;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );

    return l;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("ListViewAdd")
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        children: buildsteps()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an int to track number of steps and update it on button press by using `setState()`

```
class AddRecipeForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddRecipeFormState createState() => _AddRecipeFormState();
}

class _AddRecipeFormState extends State<AddRecipeForm> {

  int numberOfSteps = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //...
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        //...
          //Steps
          for(int i=0;i<numberOfSteps;i++)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: MyTextFormField(
                labelText: "Step ${i+1}",
              ),
            ),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Add step"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  numberOfSteps++;
                });
                //Add new text input field
              },
            ),
          ),
         //...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to get the for loop to work inside the form, are there any parenthasies missing?